# Apache Tomcat restart causes session clear in Java and session persist on a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, tomcat6

I have written a jsp redirect in my jsp page like this

```
<s:if test="#session.Doctor =  true ">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        top.location.href = "dashboard";
    <s:property value="#session.Doctor" />
    </script>
</s:if>
```

The tag  prints `true` in my jsp page when I restart Tomcat. But I have written a interceptor in struts which checks the session `System.out.println(session.get("doctorLogin")+"test");` and it prints `null` when I restart the page. Here I could understand that the session is cleared in java when I restart tomcat and session persist in jsp when I restart tomcat. Do anybody have an idea about how this why this session is cleared in java page and why it doesn't in jsp page when restart the tomcat. Does anybody have an idea?

I am using struts2, hibernate and tomcat6 as server

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the test in the if tag broken?

in java, the expression `session.Doctor =  true` doesn't check the value of session.Doctor. Rather, it *assigns* the value true to session.Doctor.

Try using `<s:if test="#session.Doctor == true ">` (note the second equals)